# Read Only Variable Assignment?

Tags: c++

I have a private member variable called "Probes",  Within one of my private member functions, i want to use the variable "Probes" to keep track of the number of comparisons made.  To do this I just put the variable within the loop and did Probes++ each time through.  But when I compile and run it, it says that I cannot assign to a read only variable?  How can I correct this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is a read only variable (constant) you cannot do `Probes++` (which is similar to `Probes = Probes + 1`) because constants cannot be updated. What you can do is to declare it as a variable (which you can modify while the program is executed) or just declare `Probes` as `mutable`.

Comment: I would 1 up you but I cant yet, Thank you for Your answer Petar! Very Very Helpful.

Comment: Thanks! I'm glad you found it helpful.